# Remove body padding for fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2. Excited to upgrade to 4 eventually.

For now I have a site with a fixed top navbar. Looks great.

Now, I am working on some new pages pages. I will need the top navbar to NOT be fixed for these pages.

I have

```
body {
  padding-top: 117px;
}
```

in my css as the navbar on top is integral to the site... but

**How can I "negate" this body padding for 2 pages where the navbar won't be fixed?**

I tried adding a css class

```
.negate-nav-padding {
  margin-top: -117px;
}
```

but that did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just give the body on those two pages an override class. Like this:

```
<body class="interior"></body>


body {
  padding-top: 117px;
}

body.interior {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be to add an `id` to body and just add these css rules:

```
body {
    padding-top: 117px;
}

body#special-page {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

edit: or class for example: `body.no-padding { padding-top: 0; }`